# Rails: decide to render spefic image in view based on database entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, view, model

I am relatively new to Rails and building a demo blackboard right now.

There are topics wich users can respond to. A posted opinion has a vote: positive, negative or neutral. These are selected by a checkbox.

In the topics show - view, you can see the already posted opinioins. For each opinion, there should be a thumb-up/down/neutral image rendered.

Right now, I am using HAML and formtastic for the new opinon form:

```
    =f.input :vote, :as => :radio, :label => "Your vote", |
:collection => [["positive","/images/Thumbs-up-icon.png"],["negative","/images/Thumbs-down-icon.png"],["neutral","/images/Thumbs-neutral-icon.png"]] |
```

The important part of topic show looks like this:

```
    - @opinions.each do |opinion|
[...]
        #opinion_vote
          = image_tag opinion.vote , {:height=>60}
```

As you can see, I directly save one of the three image_url ´s each time in the database for each opinion and directly use them to render the image in my topics view.

I know, this is bad on many levels, but it is the only working solution I found so far. 
My idea was to save the votes as integers like 1 for positive, 0 for neutral and -1 for negative. Next stept would be to have a case in my topic view to decide which image should be renderen. But logic in view is bad again...

But what is the best way and place in Rails to decide what kind of image should be shown? The topic controller ? The opinion model ? A helper ?  And finally: how could the code look ;) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you would use a helper possibly combined with some model methods to make accessing the data simpler.

Opinion Model

```
def neutral?
  if vote == 0
end

def positive?
  if vote == 1
end

def negative?
  if vote == 2
end
```

Opinion Helper

```
def vote_image
  vote.positive? ? 'positive.png' : vote.negative? ? 'negative.png' : 'neutral.png'
end
```

As you've said, it's best to store things like this in integers rather than as text, because they are smaller to store and more efficient for index'ing your data.